# How to set up a RESTful API with Spring to send a JSON response with Controller and Model

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to set up a RESTful API using Spring so that I can send an HTTP POST request and receive a response.

The post request that I'm testing with looks exactly like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/decide
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "previousDecisions": [0, 1, 2]
}
```

When I send that request (I'm using IntelliJ's 'Test RESTful Web Services' feature) I am getting an error response.

What I want to happen is, there is a class called `Decide` with a constructor that needs only an array of integers and its only member variable is an array of integers. I want to pass the above request to the `DecideController` to create an instance of `Decide`. Then `Decide` has a method that returns a `Node` object. I want to return a JSON version of that `Node` instance.

From what I've seen with Spring it automatically converts a Java object to a JSON format when it returns.

Here is my entire Decide class:

```
package com.thesisapp.server.jugtours.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Decide implements Serializable {

  private int[] decisionList;

  public Decide() {
    this.decisionList = new int[0];
  }

  public Decide(int[] decisionList) {
    this.decisionList = decisionList;
  }

  public Node getNode() {
    //Use the game class to get a root node for the entire story tree
    Node rootNode = (new Game()).getFullStoryTree();

    //Traverse the story tree using the decisionList to get to the current node
    Node currentNode = rootNode;
    for (int whichChild : this.decisionList) {
      currentNode = currentNode.getChild(whichChild);
    }

    return currentNode;
  }
}
```

Side Note: I just added the `implements Serializable` after doing some research and it did not have an affect on the error message I received. However adding that default constructor did have an affect on the error message.

And here is my entire DecideController class

```
package com.thesisapp.server.jugtours.web;

import com.thesisapp.server.jugtours.model.Node;
import com.thesisapp.server.jugtours.model.Decide;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

@RestController
public class DecideController {

  @PostMapping("/decide")
  public Node decide(@RequestBody Decide decide) {
    return decide.getNode();
  }
}
```

Again here is the request I am sending in:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/decide
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "previousDecisions": [0, 1, 2]
}
```

Here is what I want the response to look like, just JSON form of all the member variables from the `Node` class:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "text": "some text here",
  "decisions": [],
  "children": [],
  "speaker": 0,
  "checkpoint": true
}
```

Here are the two responses I have managed to get (before and after adding that default constructor to the `Decide` class)

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-09-04T02:31:05.762+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class com.thesisapp.server.jugtours.model.Decide]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.thesisapp.server.jugtours.model.Decide` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 3]",
  "path": "/decide"
}
```

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-09-04T01:50:03.990+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/decide"
}
```

I don't really have any idea at what is going wrong here. Let me know if I didn't provide enough info/code. I have very little experience with this stuff but I appreciate any help, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need getters/setters for `decisionList` on the `Decide` class so Jackson can properly bind to it. In addition your JSON request body does not map to the Decide object you've defined. By passing in

```
{
  "previousDecisions": [0, 1, 2]
}
```

Your Decide class should look like this:

```
public class Decide {
   private int[] previousDecisions;

   public int[] getPreviousDecisions(){
      return previousDecisions;  
   }

   public void setPreviousDecisions(int[] previousDecisions){
      this.previousDecisions = previousDecisions;
   }
}
```

So either change your field name in `Decide` from `decisionList` to `previousDecisions` and add getters/setters, or pass `decisionList` as the property in JSON and add getters/setters to the class:

```
{   
   "decisionList": [0, 1, 2]
}
```